# Android - Getting coordinates out of GeoPoint-Object

Tags: android, coordinates, mylocationoverlay

look at this:

```
MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);


    myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
    myLocationOverlay.enableCompass();
    GeoPoint myGeoPoint = myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation();
```

That works fine. But i need to save the coordinates in a variable. So i tried this:

```
myLocationLon = (double) myGeoPoint.getLongitudeE6();
```

When i run the App, this last line makes it collapse. Can you please tell me why this doesn't work ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`GeoPoint.getLongitudeE6()` and `GeoPoint.getLatitudeE6()` both return microdegrees (basically degrees * 1E6).

so you need to convert microdegrees to degrees simply write function:

```
public double microDegreesToDegrees(int microDegrees) {
    return microDegrees / 1E6;
}
```

and then

```
myLocationLon = microDegreesToDegrees(myGeoPoint.getLongitudeE6());
```

Comment: Thx, but that doesn't seem to to work. The last line causes a collapse when i try to start the app.

Comment: post your logcat that would certainly help to solve the issue.

Comment: I think the problem is, that a value for the Longitude isn't existing yet, when I call your function. Here a screen: http://www1.xup.in/exec/ximg.php?fid=35589012

Comment: myLocationLon = (myGeoPoint.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6);  //doesn't work